# iPad still connecting to Game Center Sandbox in airplane mode

Tags: ios, debugging, network-connection

This seems weird, but the iPad I have is *still successfully connecting to the Game Center Sandbox even though airplane mode is on*.  It would seem when debugging iPad the device somehow connects thru USB to internet (is this the case?)

I'm just trying to test the case where there is no internet connection and make sure there is a graceful fail.

Anyway, how do I disable internet connectivity on the iPad device then?

Comment: If you don't need debugging, then you can disconnect from your computer and run the app that way in airplane mode.

Comment: Well, there is console output I'd like to see.

Comment: I understand. Can you disconnect your computer from the internet to test?

Comment: I have just tried my app  airplane mode is on during debugging, It can't connect to internet. Are you sure its the USB?

Comment: Yes this seems really weird. What is happening is the `<Info>: 13:40:58.108646 com.apple.AVConference: GKSConnSettings: set server: {
     "gk-cdx" = "17.173.254.218:4398";
}` message is still printing, and I still get the `Welcome back, me *** Sandbox ***` message.  I did try disabling the machine's internet as well.  Is the "Sandbox connection" _local_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're logged into Game Center **on the device**, then apparently the GC login request will **always appear to work immediately** and it will say `Welcome back, PLAYERNAME *** Sandbox ***`.  I think it must be echoing the last known GC server IPs.  That doesn't mean you can reach the GC servers though.